# Trigger function of a specific component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My scenario is: I have a list of items, and each render a component. Each time one of these items is clicked, I render yet another component (much like a modal) passing the current item as props. Inside the modal component there's on button that, when clicked, should trigger back a function on the component that created it.

My items are:

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        data: "some data"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        data: "some data"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        data: "some data"
    }
]
```

The dynamic creation of each item as a component:

```
items.map(item => {
                return { key: item.id, content: <Item key={item.id} ItemObject={item}/> }
            });
```

So far so good. Inside that Item component class I have three actions that concern this question: the first is called when the Item div is clicked, the other is the item's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, and the third, called `updateStatus` update the component state. Here's the class:

**Item.js**

```
export function _updateStatus(newFlags) {
    this.setState({ flags: newFlags });
}

export default class SystemUnit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { flags: [] };
        _updateStatus = _updateStatus.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        ReactDOM.render(<Actions Item={this.props.ItemObject} />, document.getElementsByClassName("actions-wrapper")[0]);
    }
}
```

In the Actions component there's a button that, when clicked, should trigger back the `updateStatus` inside the Item that called Actions.

**Actions.js**

```
import { _updateStatus } from './Item';

export default class Actions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {flags: []}
    }
    render() {
        <button onClick={() => { _updateStatus(this.state.flags) }}>Finish</button>
    }
}
```

However, the button triggers the method on the last item of the list, not on the component that rendered it. On this example I have three items, and no matter which one is clicked the Action component button will always trigger the cange on item 3.

How do I specify for the Action component that the `updateStatus` method should be triggered on the Item component that rendered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the function from the component itself via the line:

```
import { _updateStatus } from './Item';
```

This is why you are getting the function of the last rendered `Item`

Instead try passing the function as a param:

```
 ReactDOM.render(<Actions Item={this.props.ItemObject} updateStatus={this._updateStatus} />, document.getElementsByClassName("actions-wrapper")[0]);
```

And access in Actions like:

```
render() {
    <button onClick={() => { this.props.updateStatus(this.state.flags) }}>Finish</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Importing the function from the component itself is something I saw in some forum. This way is much cleaner, though.

Comment: Yep, use the power of the props. Happy coding!